# Listen for certain keyboard input and insert to SQL Server DB

Tags: gpio, python, mysql

I have a USB NFC reader (acts as an emulated keyboard that types out the 10 digit ID number on the card when scanned).

I want an app to listen for this input and when it sees 10 digits, I want it to use them to try to update a column in a table on my SQL Server DB with the 10 digits acting as a unique identifier.

I can handle the SQL but have no idea about the (I assume) Python script to listen for 10 character input and then make an SQL connection.

After this I want it to trigger something via GPIO, but one step at a time.

After all this I need it to loop back to the beginning so it's ready for the next person to swipe their card on the NFC reader.

Any help on where to look / where to start would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is sample code not full but might help you

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import time
import sys

def main():
    with open('/dev/tty0', 'r') as tty:
        while True:
            RFID_input = tty.readline()
            // store this RFID_input to you SQL DB see the DB operation in python
```

Please see how to store data into DB using python.
Simple Tutorial for MySQL and Python : [MySQL-Python](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_database_access.htm)

Take a look at [USB RFID](http://www.instructables.com/id/USB-RFID-Python-Pub-Sub-MQTT/)

After Successful script to save into DB and then script to make **GPIO** high or low, run your script to listen the NFC Reader. Code your self and post your problem with DB and GPIO.